# killing a java process spawned by another java process

Tags: java, windows, service, process, kill

I have created a windows service in java in start of the service i have following code

```
mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\manager.exe");
```

This manager.exe spawn another java process, I can see the process in task manager as "javaw.exe".

I want to kill this process when service is stopped for this i have used the below code in stop method of service

```
mProcess.destroy();
```

But this does not work.

Note: Just as trial tried it for notepad it works fine.

So, how can get the handle to the spawned javaw.exe so that i can kill it when the service is stopped.

The question is not how to close the process from task manager but from Stop method of my service.

Comment: No This is not what I am looking for.Thank!

Comment: Why did you close the question i said you answer is not what I am looking for. I am still awaiting answer

Comment: This is not a duplicate question please umark it

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I read  "now that is what I am looking for". Sorry, not enough coffee today. or too much.

Comment: But for the record: I do think that the Java Process APIs do **not** allow you to find IDs of **child** processes. You have to somehow use "windows specific libraries" to somehow figure the ID of the newly created java - to then issue a windows command to kill that process.

Comment: Please post some working code which shows the problem you are facing with.

Comment: I believe Apache Daemon can run Java programs without creating a child process for them to run in.  Perhaps you could do the same thing?  Or use Apache Daemon or NSSM to install `manager.exe` as a separate service you can start and stop as needed?

Comment: Using apache daemon only for creating the service sorry i missed mentioning in the question :)